# JPA join fetch association table with N select generated by Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA with Hibernate3 as the implementation. I have an association table UsrGrp

```
Usr.java
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "usr_id")
private String usrId;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usr")
private List<UsrGrp> usrGrpList;

UsrGrp.java
@EmbeddedId
protected UsrGrpPK usrGrpPK;
@Column(name = "updated_by")
private String updatedBy;
@Column(name = "updated_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedDate;
@JoinColumn(name = "grp_id", referencedColumnName = "grp_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Grp grp;
@JoinColumn(name = "usr_id", referencedColumnName = "usr_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Usr usr;

Grp.java
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "grp_id")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "grp")
private List<UsrGrp> usrGrpList;
```

(Usr) 1--------* (UsrGrp) *--------1 (Grp)

When I execute the following sql.

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr FROM Usr usr LEFT JOIN FETCH usr.usrGrpList
```

Hibernate actually execute the same amount of select query as the numbers of Grp I have.

```
select grp0_.grp_id as grp1_6_0_ from grp grp0_ where grp0_.grp_id=?
select grp0_.grp_id as grp1_6_0_ from grp grp0_ where grp0_.grp_id=?
...
```

Is there anyway to avoid this N select queries? Thanks.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do... in English (no code)?

Comment: I tried to get a list of Usr with the usrGrp collection. The sql actually acheives it but with extra select query of Grp generated by Hibernate. Let's say if I have 100 Grp, Hibernate generates this sql select grp0_.grp_id as grp1_6_0_ from grp grp0_ where grp0_.grp_id=? 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can change the fetch mode from lazy to eager:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria( Usr.class )
                           .setFetchMode( "usrgrp", FetchMode.JOIN )
```

where `usrgrp` is a set in Usr.class.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have a sample with JPA Annotation?

Answer (score 0):

These queries are executed to load the `grp` of each fetched `UsrGrp`. Mark the ManyToOne from `UsrGrp` to `Grp` as lazy, and these queries should disappear. Or, if you want to load the groups in the same query, you could add a left join fetch to the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr FROM Usr usr 
LEFT JOIN FETCH usr.usrGrpList userGroup 
LEFT JOIN FETCH userGroup.grp grp
```

You might also enable [batch fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-batch) to reduce the number of queries.

PS: Vowels are cool. UserGroup is much more readable than UsrGrp